# Teamcity not building my .SLN in release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, teamcity, solution

I have created a release configuration project in Teamcity 6.5 using the "SLN Runner" for VS 2008 solutions.  My debug solution builds fine along with the PDB files - however I simply cannot get the thing to build in Release mode, plus it will insist on defaulting to x64 architecture.

I have tried the following:

- Set proj file explicitly to Release mode
- Set build parameters to send to MSBuild explicitly passing through /platform:anycpu and /configuration:release

I've noticed in the .sln.proj file that is generated that the following code appears (at first glance) to be incorrect and the configs are being set to Debug mode for both configurations?

```
 <ItemGroup Condition=" ('$(Configuration)' == 'Debug') and ('$(Platform)' == 'Any CPU') ">
    <BuildLevel0 Include="MySolution.csproj">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </BuildLevel0>
  </ItemGroup>


<ItemGroup Condition=" ('$(Configuration)' == 'Release') and ('$(Platform)' == 'Any CPU') ">
    <BuildLevel0 Include="MySolution.csproj">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </BuildLevel0>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Any assistance appreciated:

Comment: so you've tried to pass /p:Configuration=Release explicitly to msbuild.exe?

Comment: Yes, it completely ignores it and sends /p:Configuration=Debug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May sound stupid but does all the Projects in your solution contain an `Any CPU` platform configuration for Release?

This has caught us out a few times with some projects only pointing at x86 etc